# FactoMineR MCA error regarding numeric values?

Tags: r

I am trying to experiment with multiple correspondence analysis (`MCA`) on a dataset containing `integer` and `factor` classes.  Naturally, looking at the [FactoMineR docs](http://factominer.free.fr/classical-methods/multiple-correspondence-analysis.html) I thought `MCA` would be appropriate.  However, I am currently running in to an error that I cannot solve.

> Error in which(unlist(lapply(listModa, is.numeric))) : 
>     argument to 'which' is not logical

The truncated output of `str` is:

```
'data.frame':   1000 obs. of  115 variables:
 $ X1  : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 ....
 $ X98 : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ X99 : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ X100: Factor w/ 3 levels "Head","Unknown",..: 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 ...
 $ X101: int  44 67 69 50 61 62 30 59 55 41 ...
 $ X102: Factor w/ 5 levels "Female","FEMALE",..: 1 1 1 3 1 3 1 3 1 1 ...
 ...
 $ X115: Factor w/ 93287 levels "","010010201001",..: 35903 1 33052 66760 41187 14553 85711 64424 63119 46155 ...
```

The dataset is too large to just put on here so I am hoping the structure and description will be sufficient.

I have made sure that the only classes in the columns are `integer` or `factor` (the same as the demo `tea` dataset).  I used `na.omit` to remove any missing data and I make sure the call to `MCA` has the column indicies passed to the appropriate arguments.

```
numerics <- as.numeric(which(sapply(df, is.numeric)))
factors <- as.numeric(which(sapply(df, is.factor)))
df.mca <- MCA(df, ncp=5, quanti.sup = numerics, quali.sup = factors, graph=FALSE)
```

The closest thing I have found is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34266186/what-does-argument-to-which-is-not-logical-mean-in-factominer-mca) but it doesn't really provide a solution for me.  I can look at the function but I don't know why my dataset is causing this error in the first place.

Any insight is appreciated.

**Edit**

Here is a subset of the data via `dput`

```
structure(list(X1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    X2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X3 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), X4 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X5 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 4L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 9L, 0L, 8L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 9L, 0L, 
    0L, 2L, 0L), X6 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
    ), X7 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), X8 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X9 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), X10 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X11 = c(0L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 35L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 
    4L, 0L, 6L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 19L, 0L, 
    3L, 0L, 0L), X12 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 13L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L), X13 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
    ), X14 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X15 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 39L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X16 = c(0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X17 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X18 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X19 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), X20 = c(2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 11L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 
    5L, 12L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 26L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), X21 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    X22 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X23 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X24 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X25 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X26 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), X27 = c(5L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 46L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    3L, 14L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 24L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 2L), X28 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
    ), X29 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X30 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X31 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X32 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X33 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), X34 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), X35 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    X36 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X37 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X38 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X39 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X40 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), X41 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), X42 = c(0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    X43 = c(0L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
    0L, 20L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X44 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X45 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X46 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X47 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L), X48 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), X49 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    X50 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X51 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X52 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X53 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X54 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), X55 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), X56 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L), 
    X57 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X58 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X59 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X60 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X61 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), X62 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), X63 = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 7L, 12L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 8L, 2L, 
    8L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 12L, 0L, 48L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L), 
    X64 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X65 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X66 = c(0L, 6L, 2L, 
    4L, 4L, 6L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 22L, 0L, 45L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 54L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X67 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    15L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 14L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X68 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    9L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L), X69 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), X70 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 14L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), X71 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
    ), X72 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X73 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X74 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X75 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X76 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 10L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X77 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), X78 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
    ), X79 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 24L, 6L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 12L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 10L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X80 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X81 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X82 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X83 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), X84 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), X85 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 
    2L, 0L, 0L, 9L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    X86 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X87 = c(0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), X88 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X89 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X90 = c(0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 24L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), X91 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), X92 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L
    ), X93 = c(2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 5L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L), X94 = c(0L, 
    6L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X95 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L), X96 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X97 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), X98 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), X99 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L), .Label = c("N", "Y"), class = "factor"), X100 = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Head", "Unknown"
    ), class = "factor"), X101 = c(44L, 67L, 69L, 50L, 61L, 62L, 
    30L, 59L, 55L, 41L, 61L, 69L, 56L, 84L, 75L, 82L, 71L, 60L, 
    62L, 62L, 68L, 67L, 68L, 53L, 59L), X102 = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Female", 
    "Male"), class = "factor"), X103 = structure(c(3L, 6L, 6L, 
    5L, 6L, 9L, 10L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 
    4L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 8L, 7L, 6L), .Label = c("0: No data available", 
    "1: Under $15,000", "3: $20,000 - $29,999", "4: $30,000 - $39,999", 
    "5: $40,000 - $49,999", "6: $50,000 - $74,999", "7: $75,000 - $99,999", 
    "9: $125,000 - $149,999", "A: $150,000 - $174,999", "B: $175,000 - $199,999"
    ), class = "factor"), X104 = structure(c(3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Married", "Single", 
    "Unknown", "Widowed", "Widow or Widower", "Widow/Widower"
    ), class = "factor"), X105 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("U", "Y"), class = "factor"), 
    X106 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L
    ), .Label = c("Deferrer", "Involved", "Loyal", "Self Reliant"
    ), class = "factor"), X107 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
    3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
    1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Commercial", "Medicaid", 
    "Medicare", "Other", "Self"), class = "factor"), X108 = structure(c(2L, 
    3L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
    1L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 3L), .Label = c("Dormant", 
    "Periodic", "Prospect", "Recent", "Recurring", "Sporadic"
    ), class = "factor"), X109 = structure(c(5L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 
    1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 5L), .Label = c("African American", "Client - Non Hispanic/Latino", 
    "Jewish", "Scandinavian", "Uncoded ", "Western European"), class = "factor"), 
    X110 = structure(c(3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L
    ), .Label = c("Completed College", "Completed High School", 
    "Not available", "Some college"), class = "factor"), X111 = structure(c(11L, 
    23L, 16L, 13L, 6L, 21L, 4L, 10L, 9L, 15L, 24L, 14L, 8L, 7L, 
    22L, 2L, 20L, 1L, 3L, 19L, 5L, 12L, 25L, 18L, 17L), .Label = c("07869", 
    "07960", "17747", "20105", "21206", "21218", "22003", "22602", 
    "27344", "27370", "40214", "42351", "43081", "48180", "48235", 
    "51542", "55124", "63376", "64151", "72023", "80422", "80918", 
    "85204", "85351", "97439"), class = "factor"), X112 = structure(c(5L, 
    2L, 4L, 12L, 6L, 3L, 15L, 10L, 10L, 7L, 2L, 7L, 15L, 15L, 
    3L, 11L, 1L, 11L, 14L, 9L, 6L, 5L, 13L, 9L, 8L), .Label = c("AR", 
    "AZ", "CO", "IA", "KY", "MD", "MI", "MN", "MO", "NC", "NJ", 
    "OH", "OR", "PA", "VA"), class = "factor"), X113 = structure(c(7L, 
    1L, 5L, 16L, 8L, 4L, 22L, 15L, 14L, 9L, 1L, 9L, 21L, 20L, 
    3L, 13L, 2L, 13L, 18L, 11L, 19L, 6L, 17L, 12L, 10L), .Label = c("04013", 
    "05085", "08041", "08047", "19155", "21091", "21111", "24510", 
    "26163", "27037", "29165", "29183", "34027", "37037", "37151", 
    "39049", "41039", "42035", "510", "51059", "51069", "51107"
    ), class = "factor"), X114 = structure(c(8L, 1L, 6L, 19L, 
    9L, 5L, 24L, 18L, 17L, 10L, 2L, 11L, 23L, 22L, 4L, 15L, 3L, 
    16L, 21L, 13L, 1L, 7L, 20L, 14L, 12L), .Label = c("", "04013071504", 
    "05085020201", "08041000202", "08047013800", "19155021400", 
    "21091960200", "21111012202", "24510270903", "26163539200", 
    "26163583700", "27037060825", "29165030102", "29183311331", 
    "34027043500", "34027045603", "37037020200", "37151030504", 
    "39049006990", "41039000707", "42035030900", "51059450800", 
    "51069051000", "51107611801"), class = "factor"), X115 = structure(c(8L, 
    1L, 6L, 19L, 9L, 5L, 24L, 18L, 17L, 10L, 2L, 11L, 23L, 22L, 
    4L, 15L, 3L, 16L, 21L, 13L, 1L, 7L, 20L, 14L, 12L), .Label = c("", 
    "040130715044", "050850202011", "080410002024", "080470138004", 
    "191550214002", "210919602003", "211110122024", "245102709033", 
    "261635392003", "261635837001", "270370608253", "291650301021", 
    "291833113312", "340270435001", "340270456031", "370370202002", 
    "371510305041", "390490069901", "410390007071", "420350309002", 
    "510594508002", "510690510002", "511076118012"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("X1", 
"X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6", "X7", "X8", "X9", "X10", "X11", 
"X12", "X13", "X14", "X15", "X16", "X17", "X18", "X19", "X20", 
"X21", "X22", "X23", "X24", "X25", "X26", "X27", "X28", "X29", 
"X30", "X31", "X32", "X33", "X34", "X35", "X36", "X37", "X38", 
"X39", "X40", "X41", "X42", "X43", "X44", "X45", "X46", "X47", 
"X48", "X49", "X50", "X51", "X52", "X53", "X54", "X55", "X56", 
"X57", "X58", "X59", "X60", "X61", "X62", "X63", "X64", "X65", 
"X66", "X67", "X68", "X69", "X70", "X71", "X72", "X73", "X74", 
"X75", "X76", "X77", "X78", "X79", "X80", "X81", "X82", "X83", 
"X84", "X85", "X86", "X87", "X88", "X89", "X90", "X91", "X92", 
"X93", "X94", "X95", "X96", "X97", "X98", "X99", "X100", "X101", 
"X102", "X103", "X104", "X105", "X106", "X107", "X108", "X109", 
"X110", "X111", "X112", "X113", "X114", "X115"), row.names = c(414721L, 
73797L, 281098L, 376819L, 33586L, 462430L, 452574L, 5913L, 412768L, 
460097L, 431932L, 403489L, 407344L, 295527L, 157897L, 197133L, 
465379L, 22316L, 358357L, 178178L, 293092L, 314823L, 186844L, 
184603L, 343412L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you just do something like `dput(head(df))` to provide a small sample data set that reproduces the problem ?

Comment: @steveb sample set added

Comment: Do you still get the same error with this subset of data ?

Comment: @steveb yes, I get the same error still

Comment: Ultimately you need to create a reproducible example with a small input data set.  How is `listModa` set, is it `df.mca` ?

Comment: @steveb I gave you the small data set that reproduces the error.  There is no `listModa` as it is internal to `MCA`.  The only dataset is `df` which I am passing to `MCA` to create `df.mca`.

Comment: I am getting an error when running `MCA(df, ncp=5, quanti.sup = numerics, quali.sup = factors, graph=FALSE)`

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon the same problem, and even if it might not interest OP anymore I hope it could help someone else.

What I did first was transform all my numeric data to factor :

```
Xfac = factor(X[,1], ordered = TRUE)
for (i in 2:29){
  tfac = factor(X[,i], ordered = TRUE)
  Xfac = data.frame(Xfac, tfac)
}
colnames(Xfac)=labels(X[1,])
```

Still, it would not work. But my 2nd problem was (and I think it was yours as well) that I included EVERY factor as supplementary variable !
So these :

```
MCA(Xfac, quanti.sup = c(1:29), graph=TRUE)
MCA(Xfac, quali.sup = c(1:29), graph=TRUE)
```

Would generate the same error, but this one works :

```
MCA(Xfac, graph=TRUE)
```

Not transforming the data to factors also generated the problem.

Comment: transforming numerical/character data into factor solved my problem.